# How to minus off the elements of the tuples by it's own index or with some values in python

Tags: python, tuples, element, subtraction

```
R = [(1, 2,3,4), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1,4, 5), (1, 6), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6), (4, 5), (4, 6), (5, 6)]
```

From the above set i just want to minus off the index or any values from the each element of the tuple.

And the expected answer would be

```
#R = [(1-0, 2-0,3-0,4-0), (1-1, 3-1), (1-2, 4-2) and so on
```

here is my code but i want it in a simplest way pls help

```
final_matches = {k: v for k,v in matches.items() if len(v) >= 4}

    for k, v in matches.items():
        if len(v) >= 3:
            print(k,':',v,'/',len(v))
            #for j in range(0,len(v)):
                #print(v[j])
```

Comment: should it be string presentation `1-0` or arithmetic result?

Comment: no no just i need that value

Comment: (1,2,3,4) (0,2) like that

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
R = [(1, 2,3,4), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1,4, 5), (1, 6), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6), (4, 5), (4, 6), (5, 6)]

new_list = [tuple(c-i for c in a) for i, a in enumerate(R)]
```

to get only tuples with length three:

```
new_list = [i for i in new_list if len(i) >= 3]
```

Final output:

```
[(1, 2, 3, 4), (-2, 1, 2)]
```

Comment: for k, v in matches.items():
    if len(v) >= 3:
        print(k,':',v,'/',len(v))    here v is my tuple and i need to minus with k for each iteration for all the element of the tuple. pls

Comment: do you mean that you want just the tuples which are of length greater than or equal to 3?

Comment: Yes bro u r exactly right...i have tuple v and i need to minust that elements with k that's all

Comment: print(k,':',v,'/',len(v)) in this line v is a tuple and k is a integer and i need to minus the k with all the elements of the tuple...how !?

Comment: The operation that you wish performed is carried out in new_list. Could you post the dictionary that you created, final_matches? I am using a list with a tuple, while you have a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

`v[:] = [x - k for x in v]` can do this when you iterate through the dict.